# Would this circuit work? This is too complex for me

Tags: led, switches, dc-motor, circuit-design

Long story short, I want to make a picture frame with a lot of electronic components for my friends birthday.

I'd like to use an USB phone charger as the source. It's 5V dc with 2A, so I guess overall that makes 10 W power. In parallel I'd like to connect three main components that each would be activated with switches. You could run all three of these components at the same time, enabling or disabling any of them whenever you want.

On the first rail there would be an mp3 module that is 3w at 5v USB GPD2846A to be precise. To it I would connect a 3w speaker rated at 4 ohms.

The second rail would have a switch and a motor that would spin a fan. It operates at 3 v to 6 v. All things considered it should work with the 5 v USB source.

Third rail would have a switch that would activate 6 leds (3 connected in pairs, every two leds protected by resistors).

I made a scheme of the circuit to make it easier to understand of what I desire. Not sure if this circuit is possible since I'm a complete noob when it comes to electronics, but from what I gathered this should work? Thanks! [image]

Comment: First test each of these systems, independently, using your chosen power supply. Just do it on a table top and check things out. Also, put an ammeter in series and document the required current in each case. If they work fine for you, one at a time, and their current readings are smaller than your power supply nameplate rating, then move to the step of considering the idea of turning all three of them on at the same time when all three are attached. But first add up the three current numbers and again check the sum as smaller than the power supply's rating. Do everything in steps.

Comment: And watch that the startup current of the fan doesn't cause the 5 V to dip for a moment or latch in current limit mode.

Comment: Looks ok to me.